# How to redirect Vue app to login page on 401 error?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios, vue-router

In my Vue.js component I make async call to API on mounted lifecycle hook:

```
mounted() {
this.getDataFromApi()
  .then(data => {
    this.events = data.data;
    this.totalEvents = data.meta.total;
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    if (error.response.status === 401) {
      console.log(error.response.status);
      this.$router.push({ name: 'auth.login'})
    }
  });
```

},

I want to redirect user to login page on 401. But I'm getting this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property '$router' of undefined
```

How do I redirect user to login page?

Comment: `this` inside the callback will not be vue component object but probably window object. So, keep the Vue object in a local variable outside the callback and use that variable inside instead of `this`. Maybe `var me=this;` then later in callback `me.$router.push(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was about the scope: in catch you should use an arrow function like this:

```
.catch((error) => {
if (error.response.status === 401) {
  this.$router.push({ name: 'auth.login'})
}
```

});